# Powershell command for azure data protection

Tags: azure, powershell

I need the PowerShell command to get information about Data protection in my azure subscription.

I'm able to get information about PITR and others option, but not the 'Enable azure backup for blobs' option.

[image: the option i want]

I try the `Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupProtectionPolicy` command but I can't make it work.

Is there another way to get this information with PowerShell or Az command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There is no **direct command** to retrieve the information about Data protection in entire Azure Subscription.

In my case, I ran below PowerShell script and got **response** successfully with required details like this:

```
$Subid = "subscription_id"
$rgnames = Get-AzResourceGroup

foreach ($rgname in $rgnames) {
    $rgn = $rgname.ResourceGroupName
    $vaults = Get-AzDataProtectionBackupVault -ResourceGroupName $rgn

    foreach ($vault in $vaults) {
        $vname = $vault.Name
        $ResourceN = Get-AzDataProtectionBackupInstance -SubscriptionId $Subid -ResourceGroupName $rgn -VaultName $vname
        $instanceName = $ResourceN.BackupInstanceName.Split('-')[0]
        $policy = Get-AzDataProtectionBackupPolicy -SubscriptionId $Subid -ResourceGroupName $rgn -VaultName $vname

        Write-Output "--------------------------------------------------"
        Write-Output "Data Protection Resource : $($instanceName)" 
        Write-Output "DatasourceType : $($policy.DatasourceType)"
        Write-Output "Resource Group: $($rgn)"
        Write-Output "Vault Name: $($vname)"
        Write-Output "Policy Name: $($policy.Name)"
    }
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

**References:**

[Get-AzDataProtectionBackupInstance (Az.DataProtection) | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.dataprotection/get-azdataprotectionbackupinstance?view=azps-11.0.0)

[Get-AzDataProtectionBackupPolicy (Az.DataProtection) | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.dataprotection/get-azdataprotectionbackuppolicy?view=azps-11.0.0)